# Poppler-Qt5 Failing to renderto

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get this function to work, but right now the output is always false when it tries to paint to the pixmap object.

```
void MainWindow::PDF(){
    QString path = "D:\\Translation.pdf";
    Poppler::Document *doc = Poppler::Document::load(path);
    Poppler::Page* pdfPage1 = doc->page(0);
    Poppler::Page* pdfPage2 = doc->page(1);
    //QImage image = pdfPage->renderToImage(1080,1080,-1,-1,-1,-1);
    QPixmap *pix = new QPixmap(1080,1080);
    QPainter *paint1 = new QPainter(pix);
    if (pdfPage1->renderToPainter(paint1 ,1080,1080,-1,-1,-1,-1)){
        qDebug() << true;
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << false;
    }
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->addPixmap(*pix);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poppler renders PDF in Qt4 using two different backends: `Arthur` and `Splash`. So of the methods are not implemented in `ArthurBackend`, and some in `SplashBackend`. Your error is perhaps the result of that. `Poppler::Page::renderToPainter(...)` has been implemented only for `Arthur Backend`. My guess is that in your case, the rendering backend is `Splash`, and hence `::renderToPainter(...)` returns `false`. ([Documentation](https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/classPoppler_1_1Page.html#a11e1a778fe419619399dd5308b8d3995))

You can check the backend using `Poppler::Document::renderBackend()`. By default, the rendering is done by `Splash Backend`. ([Documentation](https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/classPoppler_1_1Document.html#a5998fa2b71aac88b53c62ef5d2ac0f3b))